# Xpath select only part of an attribute

Tags: xpath, attributes, replace

if

```
/dt/@id
```

returns `comment_34232` or `comment_12` how can I make it return `34232` or `12` (in other words replaceing `'comment_'` with `''`

and if

```
/span/style
```

returns `width: 80%;` how can I replace  `width:` and after that `%;` to retrieve `80`

Regards

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for two one-liner XPath expressions that return exactly the data you are asking for in your two questions. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**I. Part**

> if
>
> ```
> /dt/@id returns `comment_34232` or `comment_12` how can I make it return
> ```
>
> `34232` or `12` (in other words
>   replaceing `'comment_'` with `''`

**Use**:

```
substring-after(/dt/@id, '_')
```

**II. Part**

> and if
>
> ```
> /span/style returns `width: 80%;` how can I replace  `width: ` and after
> ```
>
> that `%;` to retrieve `80`

**Use**:

```
substring-before(substring-after(/span/style, ' '), '%')
```

**Do note**: the use of the standard XPath functions [**`substring-before()`**](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#function-substring-before) and [**`substring-after()`**](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#function-substring-after) .