# xpath expression to select attribute value

Tags: xpath

Is there an xpath way to select a given attribute value?

For example I have an html document and want to select only "?ms=669601" :

```
<input type="button" value="تفاصيل" onclick="xmlreqGET("?ms=669601","jm1x");">
```

Comment: I found something simular on Stackoverflow:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4720480/xpath-select-only-part-of-an-attribute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your simple example, you could simply select that portion of the `onclick` attribute in the only `input`:

```
substring(input/@onclick, 12, 10)
```

In more complicated documents, try selecting first by `@value` (or some other (possibly unique) criteria):

```
substring(//input[@value='تفاصيل']/@onclick, 12, 10)
```

Or by targeting the `input` that contains part of the desired substring:

```
substring(//input[contains(@onclick, 'xmlreqGET(')]/@onclick, 12, 10)
```

Selecting the `input` element itself if its `onclick` attribute contains the target string:

```
//input[contains(@onclick, '?ms=669601')]
```

**Note:** Your input is not valid XML, due to nested double-quotes.

Comment: thank youuuuuu.this works fine :substring(//input[@value='تفاصيل']/@onclick, 12, 10)

Comment: @ lwburk this select only one .in my code there are many <input type="button" value="تفاصيل" onclick="xmlreqGET("?ms=....","jm..");"> how i select all .

Comment: @NouNou - In that case you probably want to select all the elements that have that substring (something like my last expression above). The string functions are going to return a string. If you want multiple strings, then you need to approach this from a higher level (i.e. the element level).